# Screenshot using asl library

Tags: android, screenshot

I am using asl-native library for taking screenshot. I tried it on two phones. 
1. Samsung Galaxy Y, Gingerbread, unrooted 
2. Nexus S, Jellybean 4.2, rooted 
It is taking screenshot on Galaxy Y even through the phone is not rooted. 
On Nexus S, rooted phone,  it allows me to run chmod 0777. I am able to copy asl native and set the rights. But when I run it, it says "asl native service not found". 
I require to run it on Nexus S as I have to perform some processing. 
What could be the issue? 
I found a question on asl https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542092/screen-capture-using-asl-library, but it has no replies.

Comment: did you have any success ?

Comment: may I have your skype id? want's to chat

Comment: Yaa sure :) its aaswad.satpute But please make sure you ping me on G+ before it if I'm unavailable @ gplus.to/aaswad